# DJI android sdk crash on start up (only if built with macOS)

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I got exception when run app if it has been built on macOS:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX__Ljava_lang_String_2)
    at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(Native Method)
    at com.dji.g.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source:24)
    at com.dji.g.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source:5)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source:2)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
```

Before this exception I got this one:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.gg.wp-D5RSHkictI89woc7FOnlUQ==/lib/arm64/libSDKRelativeJNI.so" .dynamic section has invalid offset: 0x1c350, expected to match PT_DYNAMIC offset: 0x0
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
    at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source:2)
    at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(Native Method)
    at com.dji.g.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source:24)
    at com.dji.g.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source:5)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.<clinit>(Unknown Source:2)
    at dji.sdk.sdkmanager.DJISDKManager.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
```

But if I built same project on Windows it works correctly.
I run app on real devices (Samsung Galaxy S10) so it not x86 ffmpeg issue.

How can I fix this??

Comment: I meet the same problem, and I had solved this problem.
[you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57671093/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found-for-byte-dji-midware-n/57719917#57719917)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these lines to gradle.build fix problem:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"

    doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
    doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
}
```