# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX

Tags: java, dji-sdk

**SDK Version** :

```
com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9
com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9
com.dji:dji-sdk:4.9
```

**Android Studio Version**:
3.5.0

**Gradle Version** : 
5.4.1

**Android device Version** :
5.1.1  (huawei pad)

**enviroment** :
muti moudle and dji-sdk not import in main moudle

**problem description**: 
I had init sdk in my application first,when I run project,program crash when init and then I got this problem in logcat.
can you help me?
thanx very much!
I had tried  Dji-SDK  4.10 also but doesn't work still

gradle:

```
api ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.9'){
  exclude group: 'com.vividsolutions'
}
  api('com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.9') {
  exclude group: 'com.vividsolutions'
}
compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.9'
```

my application

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    com.secneo.sdk.Helper.install(this);
}
```

**found error**:

```
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for byte[] dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(java.lang.String) (tried Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX and Java_dji_midware_natives_SDKRelativeJNI_native_1getXXXX__Ljava_lang_String_2)
at dji.midware.natives.SDKRelativeJNI.native_getXXXX(Native Method)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved the problem after three days

1.open your project "local.properties" file ,and you can see

```
## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Thu Aug 29 17:07:04 CST 2019
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

and now you just add one line on the previous line of the SDK path

```
ndk.dir=
```

results

```
## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Thu Aug 29 17:07:04 CST 2019
ndk.dir=
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

2.now,you should be open your sdk.dir and find out like "ndk" or "ndk-bundle" folder ,then delete them(if you dont want to delete,you can rename like"ndk-test" , "ndk-bundle-test" or others you like). Don't worry about that, if you need to edit the NDK function,you can download in SDK-manager.but if you want build this project ,you must do it.

3.finally , rebuild,just so easy!!